# I need easy way to make depended DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdownlist of car brands:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
           model => model.Brand, 
       new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = "Opel" , text = "Opel" },
                   new { value = "Lada" , text = "Lada" },
                   new { value = "BMW" , text = "BMW"}
                },

              "value",
              "text"
```

As you can see, i was too lazy for making any classes, and thies code at the View.

How can i make a second dropdownlist: with car models ? I mean that user selects "Opel" and then can select "Corsa" or "Vectra" but not "X6" or "2110" ?

Looking for the most simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a cascading dropdown, probably using ajax.

This tutorial was almost made perfectly for you (car themed)
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx